# Update Table Row Value with Post Button

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in my mysql database which I am displaying in table using PHP like below

[image]

```
$requirement_qry="SELECT t1.*, t2.id as unit_id, t2.name as unit_name FROM `tbl_requirements` 
t1 INNER JOIN tbl_units AS t2 on unit_type = t2.id AND project_id='".$_GET['project_id']."' AND user_id='".$userid."'";
$requirement_result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$requirement_qry);

                <form action="" name="addeditcategory" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input  type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['project_id'];?>" />

          <div class="section">
            <div class="section-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" >Project Name :-</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['project_id'])){echo $row['name'];}?> " class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" >Location :-</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['project_id'])){echo $row['location'];}?> " class="form-control" disabled>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Project Status :-</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">

                          <select name="status" id="status" class="select2" disabled>
                            <?php if (!isset($_GET['project_id'])) { ?>
                            <option value="1">--Project Status--</option>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <option value="1" <?php echo $row['status'] == '1' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Open</option>                            
                            <option value="2" <?php echo $row['status'] == '2' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Closed</option>                            
                        </select>

                </div>
              </div>



               <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label class="control-label">Project Details :-</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <textarea  name="details" id="details" rows="4" class="form-control" disabled><?php echo stripslashes($row['details']);?></textarea>

                </div>
              </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label class="control-label">Project Requirements :-</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <table id="t01">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Requirements</th> 
                        <th>Required</th>
                        <th>Sent</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $no     = 1;
                            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($requirement_result))
                            {
                                $id = $row1['id'];
                                $unit_name = $row1['unit_name'];
                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="reqId" id= "reqId" value="'.$id.'" />';
                                echo '<tr>
                                        <td>'.$no.'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row1['name'].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$row1['unit_required']." ".$unit_name.'</td>
                                        <td><input type="number" id = "received" name = "received" value ="'.$row1['unit_received'].'"/></td>
                                        <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:5px 10px;">Submit</button></td>
                                    </tr>';
                                $no++;
                            }?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Above code is properly displaying my data. I have one field value from row need to update using submit button. Its working fine if there only one row...if there multiple row, its not updating data of it except last row. 
My submit code is like below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_POST['project_id']))
{       

        $projectId = $_GET['project_id'];

        $data = array(
                     'unit_received'  =>  $_POST['received']
                    );      
                 $unit_edit=Update('tbl_requirements', $data, " WHERE id = '".$_POST['reqId']."'");
                 print_r($unit_edit);
                 echo $unit_edit;


        if ($unit_edit > 0)
        { 

                    $_SESSION['msg']="11"; 
                    header( "Location:view_open_project.php?project_id=".$_POST['project_id']);
                    exit;

        }
}
```

I am little new in PHP, Let me know if someone can help me for solve the bug.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You've already asked and deleted this question because it got downvoted!!

Comment: @KebabProgrammer i was have corrected as much as possible but unable to solve it, thats the reason I have posted it again. Thanks

Comment: This code doesn't work because you didnt wrap the divs in a `<form></form>` element, so submit button doesn't know where to pass the submitted data to

Comment: It have and even working if row is single, its not work if row is multiple. I have just copied required code only here.

Comment: The input name will duplicate since you use loop.

Comment: @Saji Let me know if you can help me for correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @Saji has already stated, you are replicating your name through the loop.You should rather use

```
echo '<input  type="hidden" name="reqId[]" id= "reqId" value="'.$id.'" />';
```

Note the `[]` brackets that were appended so that you create an array of names.
To update, you need a loop like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['reqId']);$i++){
    $unit_edit=Update('tbl_requirements', $data, " WHERE id = '".$_POST['reqId'][$i]."'");
}
```

Comment: Its updating value of all row, I want update single row instead of all.....there separate button for each row as you can see in image.

Comment: Ooh my bad , I didn't even see the images

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just create a hidden form where you will keep original elements. When the save button click you just find the actual value and set this to the elements inside hidden form, then trigger the submit button inside hidden form.

Note the changes I have done on your code.

1.Removed the hidden element `reqId` from inside loop.

2.Given a class name to the button inside loop and changed the button type from `submit` to `button`. Added data attribute `data-id="'.$id.'"`.

3.The input `received` inside the loop has given unique id and name by concatenated the `$id`.

4.Created hidden form with hidden input in it. It has your actual input names.

5.Created a jquery function to attach click event to the button inside loop.

6.Moved the hidden element `project_id` to inside hidden form.

Now see the below code for more details. Hope this will help you..

```
 <form action="" name="addeditcategory" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['project_id']; ?>"/>

                    <div class="section">
                        <div class="section-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Project Name :-</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['project_id'])) {
                                        echo $row['name'];
                                    } ?> " class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Location :-</label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['project_id'])) {
                                        echo $row['location'];
                                    } ?> " class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Project Status :-</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">

                                    <select name="status" id="status" class="select2" disabled>
                                        <?php if (!isset($_GET['project_id'])) { ?>
                                            <option value="1">--Project Status--</option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <option value="1" <?php echo $row['status'] == '1' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Open</option>
                                        <option value="2" <?php echo $row['status'] == '2' ? 'selected' : ''; ?> >Closed</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <label class="control-label">Project Details :-</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <textarea name="details" id="details" rows="4" class="form-control"
                                              disabled><?php echo stripslashes($row['details']); ?></textarea>

                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <label class="control-label">Project Requirements :-</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <table id="t01">
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Requirements</th>
                                            <th>Required</th>
                                            <th>Sent</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        $no = 1;
                                        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($requirement_result)) {
                                            $id = $row1['id'];
                                            $unit_name = $row1['unit_name'];
                                            echo '<tr>
                                                        <td>' . $no . '</td>
                                                        <td>' . $row1['name'] . '</td>
                                                        <td>' . $row1['unit_required'] . " " . $unit_name . '</td>
                                                        <td><input type="number" id = "received' . $id . '" name = "received' . $id . '" value ="' . $row1['unit_received'] . '"/></td>
                                                        <td><button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-click" data-id="' . $id . '" style="padding:5px 10px;">Submit</button></td>
                                                    </tr>';
                                            $no++;
                                        } ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </form>

                <form action="" id="addeditcategory_temp" name="addeditcategory_temp" method="post" class="form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none;>
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['project_id']; ?>"/>
                    <input  type="hidden" name="reqId" id= "reqId" value="" />
                    <input type="number" id = "received" name = "received" value ="">
                    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding:5px 10px;">

                </form>

                <script>

                    $(document).ready(function(e){
                        $('.submit-click').off('click').on('click', function(e){
                            var reqId = $(this).data('id');
                            var received =  $('#received'+reqId).val();
                            var form = $('#addeditcategory_temp');
                            form.find('#reqId').val(reqId);
                            form.find('#received').val(received);
                            form.find('#submitButton').trigger('click');
                        })
                    });
                </script>
```